# jquery multiplication of identical text fields?

Tags: jquery

i have a code pen  link, in it i have 3 text fields. if i enter 3 in the second text field 3*5=15 should come in in first text field(working), when i enter 4 in the second text field 4*5=20 and 20 + 15 (previous) =35 should come in first text,

that mean last 2 text field value will be multiplied by 5 and their some should come in the first text field.

the problem is you are not support to change class name or id name of text field.
how to do it?

```
         <input type="text" id="amount"/>

          first:<input type="number" class="quantity"/>
          second:<input type="number" class="quantity"/>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gwjLpa#anon-signup)

Comment: Don't use links to code, put the code in the question please - links are susceptible to rot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `each` and the selector `.quantity[value!=""]` to only get inputs with a value.

```js
jQuery('.quantity').change(function() {
  var amount = 0;
  jQuery('.quantity[value!=""]').each(function() {
    amount += this.value * 5;
  });
  jQuery('#amount').val(amount);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="amount" />first:

<input type="number" class="quantity" />second:
<input type="number" class="quantity" />
```

Answer (score 1):

if I understand well, you want to calc into 1st field the sum of the 2 others. If so try this:

```
$('.quantity').change(function()
{
    var amount = $(this).val() * 5
                 + $(this).siblings('.quantity').val() * 5;
    $('#amount').val(amount);
});
```

**[EDIT]** add a note about the use of jQuery / $

> By the way, unless you work in no conflict mode (with another lib) you can use the `$` instead of jQuery, faster to write and more standard!

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".quantity").change(function(){
var amount =0;
       $('.quantity[value!=""]').each(function() {
    amount += this.value * 5;
  });
$('#amount').val(amount );
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="amount"/>

          first:<input type="number" class="quantity"/>
          second:<input type="number" class="quantity"/> 

</body>
</html>
```